# Mysql - How to Give Alias name for column

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the list of tables that matches the query string from the database.

### My Query

```
show tables like '%fit%'
```

### Output

**Tables_in_pdi (%fit%)**

```
fit_types
```

In PHP while i am fetching these , i am getting the output as

```
Array ( [Tables_in_pdi (%fit%)] => fit_types )
```

If there is an anyway to give alias for these , so that it will be easy for me to take the data in php

Comment: You want to get the tables that have the word  like "fit". Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be easier to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'DB_NAME'
  AND table_name LIKE '%fit%'
```